# The farmer can see it but the god can't

Tags: riddle

> Farmer can see it everyday,
>
> King can see it once a month
>
> but God can't see it.

What is it?

(I do not ask about mathematicians or some other things and the answer is not the same so it is not a duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is

> Someone with higher post than himself
>  Practically everyone is seen as a higher rank than a farmer
>  Kings hardly ever see another king or an emperor
>  God cannot see higher diety than himself

Comment: Is this meant to be a comment or answer? If it's an answer, can  you explain how it relates to the puzzle? Such short, unexplained answers are likely to be deleted.

Comment: I went ahead and fixed your post for you, you can let it get peer reviewed or just accept it. Whichever you like. Feel free to look at the edit to see how I did the spoiler tag. Note: there are 2 spaces at the end of each line.

Comment: With the clarification, I actually find this more accurate than the accepted answer. The King line still doesn't quite fit, though.

Comment: I know my answer is not perfect (it was half joke), but I really don't get the line with the king in this one. Can someone explain it to me? It looks like every king sees "bigger" king (because of "higher post") once a month and it is nonsense...

Comment: Actually there is nothing God cannot see. We human are not capable of understanding God like computers cannot understand humans.

Answer (score 4):

The answer could be:

> **Taxes**
>  Farmer has to pay tax every day.
>  King sees it once per month when he gets taxes.
>  And I don't know which God has to pay them.

Don't know if this is the correct answer but I have to post it ;-).

Comment: Ahhh. It makes sense now why the churches are exempt.

Comment: I know it's already been accepted but I'm not clear on the validity of this. I have question for @CenkArslan . What kind of farmer has to pay tax every day? What king collects taxes once a month? Why can't God see taxes even though he doesn't pay or collect them?

Comment: @EngineerToast my answer was a "half joke". But I really don't get why my answer was accepted and it was changed to some other answer which has completely different answer... It looks like even Cenk Arslan don't know the correct answer ;-).